# How do I place a PFQueryCollectionView in a scrollview?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to place a PFQueryCollectionView in a scroll view, but it keeps crashing with this error `[UICollectionViewController loadView] instantiated view controller with identifier "first" from storyboard "Main", but didn't get a UICollectionView.'` The cell identifier is correct as well as the storyboard id. I think I know what is wrong. It is trying to place a view controller inside the scroll view, but instead is retrieving a PFQueryCollectionView class.

Scroll View

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let page: pageone = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("first") as! pageone
```

Collection View

```
class pageone: PFQueryCollectionViewController{

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFCollectionViewCell? {
    var cell: PFCell = collectionview.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PFCell
    cell.name.text = object!["Name"] as? String
    return cell
}


}
```

Comment: PFQueryCollectionView is already a embedded inside a scroll view so you do not need to manually put it inside a scroll view.

Comment: No like I have multiple collection views and I am putting it into one scroll view. It works when the class is a view controller and not a PFCollectionView.

Comment: In that case you can use a custom uicollectionView instead PFCollectionViewController

Comment: When I do that and I run a query to get data from parse the scroll view lags. Any way to fix that?

Comment: Another way is to have container view inside scroll view and assign container view as PFQueryCollectionViewController

Comment: Are you querying in the main thread? That might cause lagging.

Comment: I am reloading the collection view on the main thread

Comment: That is causing the lagging. Load the pfquery in background thread.